# Chrome browser does not show images generated by HTTP handler

Tags: asp.net, html, google-chrome

Basically I have a web site that renders HTML preview of some documents (mainly office). The resulting HTML fragment is included in the page returned by the same web site, however images are returned by HTTP handler from another site with the following links:

```
<img width="50" height="50" src="http://portal/Service/GetFile.asxh?id=123&inline=true">
```

For some reason all browsers except Chrome (e.g. IE6/7/8, Firefox, Opera, Safari) show everything just fine, however for these images Chrome shows "broken image" icon. If I choose "Open image in new tab" then the image is shown just fine.

**Edit** I thought I have solved this issue, but apparently with Fiddler turned on it works fine.

I had context.Response="utf-8" left in code, but removing it had no difference.

Headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 05 Jan 2011 14:26:57 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
MicrosoftOfficeWebServer: 5.0_Pub
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: -1
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

Code:

```
                    context.Response.ContentType = file.ContentType;

                    context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

                    byte[] buff = new byte[BuffSize];
                    using (var stream = repository.GetFileContentsAsStream(file.ContentId))
                    {
                        int bytesRead;
                        do
                        {
                            bytesRead = stream.Read(buff, 0, BuffSize);
                            if (bytesRead > 0)
                            {
                                context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buff, 0, bytesRead);
                            }
                        } while (bytesRead > 0);
                    }

                    context.Response.Flush();
                    context.Response.Close();
```

Comment: Does your handler set the correct content-type?

Comment: what headers is your handler sending in the response?

Comment: Are you absolutely positive your service is generating the correct headers? I've had similar problems before and it's almost always been an issue with the headers or the stream, some browsers forgive some things that others don't. And I assume you meant "ashx" and not "asxh" :)

Comment: Also... IsReusable = false in your handler?

Comment: try adding a content-length as well to your headers

Comment: Yep, content-length did the trick.

Comment: @Pauli please post this as Answer so it's more visible to others with same problem. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm pretty sure Chrome requires the Length to be set for images, so try adding the Content-Length header to your response when handling the image.

Comment: Nope, I have exactly same system and I dont send content length either, still it works well.

Comment: Well I read images from database. Perhaps overhead adds enough delay causing Chrome to give up. Anyways, adding Content-Length fixed this problem.

Answer (score 4):

It's the context.Response.Close();  Chrome doesn't like it. Get rid of that line and all will be good.  I fought with this for months.

Comment: I think you are right. I had the same problem with a handler serving generic pdfs. It vanished after removing of the Close

Comment: Same here, also applied the Content-Length header but removing the Close() method fixed it.

Comment: I had the problem and this was my solution. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

You should add this:

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;Filename=\"Picture.gif\"");
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", filesize.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browsers#Image_format_support

My issue after trying all of the above was simply that chrome among others do not support my image type. Tiff is not supported by chrome.