# Images not showing up on first time

Tags: javascript, image, cdn, jcarousellite

Hellow everyone,
I'm having a problem on the site where my images' widths are not being calculated properly (they're not showing either on first load as well) inside jCarouselLite plugin.
I wonder if this has something to do with the fact that they're loaded from the CDN and don't have a proper content-type set (or something similar). ([Example apartment](http://dev.online-express.ru/search/apartments/apartment?city=1479&datefrom=30.03.2016&dateto=06.04.2016&rooms=1-0&meals=0+1+2+3+4&onlyAvailable=1&suppliers=20&apartment=1246719&order=))

If you check the [List of apartments](http://dev.online-express.ru/search/apartments/results?city=1479&datefrom=30.03.2016&dateto=06.04.2016&rooms=1-0&meals=0%201%202%203%204&onlyAvailable=1&suppliers=20&order=), you can go inside each one by clicking on the name or on the picture. It's INSIDE that pictures do not show up for me in any browser I've tried. If, however, I refresh the page, they show up fine.

Can anyone suggest what may be happening here?

Comment: They are working fine for me the first time I click through to an apartment list.  I am using Chrome latest on OS X El Capitan.

Comment: May it something to do with http://stackoverflow.com/a/4617654/696034 (Zero content-length)?

Comment: It looks like the problem is intermittent. We've decided to move to another carousel that does not suffer from it (hopefully, on other systems and/or browsers) as it was not dependent on the file extension type nor Content-Length in the header.